# Adding/removing Azure functions to/from existing Function App using http

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My app has a requirement to create/delete individual functions at run time. Currently AWS Lambdas are being used to do this by uploading a zip archive containing js/python scripts. I want to know if the equivalent is possible in Azure so that the app can be deployed there.

Is this possible with Azure Functions using HTTP? I see that they have a [zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) option but it appears that the zip has to contain all of the functions for the app. I want to control the functions on an individual basis. The Azure Portal UI lets me add individual functions, but I can't find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

There have a deploy method of azure function witch named [continues deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment). That allow you to do incremental deployment.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to answer my question as "No" it is not possible to deploy an individual function (as opposed to a whole function app) like you can in the portal.

`The unit of deployment for functions in Azure is the function app`